# Creating a Canvas Background Dynamically

Tags: wpf, canvas, background, drawingbrush

I currently have a canvas which contains a bunch of sqaures as its children.
These sqaures sit on different lines. 
I would like to draw a background for the canvas which draws lines (like a notepad would have feint blue lines on the paper)
I would like to draw this dynamically by binding it to a collection of "lines" 
So if there are 2 lines in the collection, 2 lines will be drawn on the background of the canvas.
I was looking into using DrawingBrush, but i am not sure if this is the correct way forward

```
<DrawingBrush>
  <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    <Line Name=Line1/>
    <Line Name=Line2/>
  </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

(BTW The above code does not work, it is just to explain the conecpt)

Comment: Cool idea, I'd like to know this also +1

Comment: So, your goal here is to use databinding and not write any code? I have some suggestions, I just want to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I would like to use databinding (not like the xaml above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach. Use a new class for your canvas:

```
internal class SpecialCanvas : Canvas
{
    ...

    ObservableCollection<Line> Lines {get; set;}

    DrawingVisual backgroundVisual = new DrawingVisual;

    public SpecialCanvas()
    {
        this.Background = new VisualBrush(backgroundVisual);   
    }

    private void OnLinesChanged(...)
    {
       using (DrawingContext dc = this.backgroundVisual.RenderOpen())
       {
           // Draw your lines to dc here.
       }
    }
```

}

Comment: This is a simmilar solution to what i was looking for, but can i use the DrawingVisual as a Background? I Dont want the line to be a child element of the Canvas(THats because i am handling drag events on the canvas and i do not want the lines to be dragged).

Comment: Yes you can. Just use VisualBrush as background.

Comment: There is no Draw() method in the DrawingVisual class?

Comment: Also i cannot use a DrawingVisual as a background directly i get the following error:

Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Background' to object of type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'. 'System.Windows.Media.DrawingVisual' is not a valid value for property 'Background'

Is it possible to use the DrawingVisual as a background?

Comment: Really, there is no Draw() method in DrawingVisual, it was my mistake. Sorry. You need to draw to your visual when your lines collection changed.

Comment: You cannot set a DrawingVisual for background, you need to create a VisualBrush with your visual.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could possibly do what you want to do.  For a simple XAML only solution, you could just use an itemscontrol.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="Lines" Type="{x:Type Line}"> 
        <Line X1="0" X2="400" Y1="25" Y2="25" Stroke="Black" />
        <Line X1="0" X2="400" Y1="25" Y2="25" Stroke="Black" />
    </x:Array>

</Window.Resources>
<Canvas>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource Lines}" />

    <Rectangle Height="20" Width="20" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="5" Stroke="Blue" Fill="Blue" />
    <Rectangle Height="20" Width="20" Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="5" Stroke="Blue" Fill="Blue" />
    <Rectangle Height="20" Width="20" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="30" Stroke="Blue" Fill="Blue" />
    <Rectangle Height="20" Width="20" Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="30" Stroke="Blue" Fill="Blue" />
</Canvas>
```